# MySQL Share user_id with users table and admins table

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, primary-key

I am creating a table for **comments** and one of the fields is `user_id`.  Well both a regular user and an administrator will be able to post a comment so I'm not sure how I would do that.

---

Users table has a primary key of `user_id`

Admins table has a primary key of `admin_id`

---

So how would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can redesign to have a single table (`login`?) with an isAdmin flag, I'd do that.

If you can't, then have a process that causes every entry in the admin table to create a related entry in the user table.  The admin table can then have a user_id field to relate the two together.

In this way every admin has a user, and all comments can be made using that user_id.

I would strongly avoid having comments keyed against *both* user_id and admin_id, with one of them being kept NULL.  It will make queries untidy, obstruct you from enforcing constraints, and tie you to he messy two-key method if you encounter a similar need anywhere else.

Comment: The only problem is that I only need a username, password, first and last name for the admins.  the users table has a bunch of fields that will not apply for the admins.  I could enter them anyway and leave the other fields NULL but the users table does not have a first and last name column which the admin needs.  so it is just two different designs

Comment: Where users don't have fields the admins do, that's not a problem.  You still have the original admin record, you keep the admin data in the admin table.  The opposite way around should be manageable too, continue to use the admin table as you did previously.  This is mearly to establish a user_id for every admin so that they can leave comments and the tables only need to use one foreign key.

Answer (score 2):

why not have all of the users and administrators in one table and have a column "isAdmin" - if user is admin set to 1, default is 0

or

your comments table should have two columns and either user_id or admin_id updated, default 0 - but this is not a nice way...

Comment: I could do that but 90% of the fields that a regular user has, the admin does not need - the admin just needs a username and password.

Comment: this would even more suggest to me not to have a separate table for admin - waist of space and speed... but i guess it's up to you. try second solution then.

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this a couple of different ways.  either have one commenter_id which links to either the user_id or the admin_id with an associated user_type flag or have two commenter_id fields, one for users and one for admins and key off of which field has a value to determine which table to go to for any related queries.   I'm sure there are other much more elegant options but these two are the quick and dirty options.

Answer (score 0):

Then you can make table -comments as

```
comment_id-int
user_id-fk from users table or admin table
user_type- enum('admin','user')
comment
```

//And other necessary fields

Comment: You can't foreign key to two separate tables.  You can have a field that 'you know' behaves this way, but then you *can't* enforce the constraint in this way.

Comment: I meant foreign key in sense that it refers to any one of table. Means user_id can be from users_table or admin_table. Column can have one to many relation.